# Protractor click() - getting element is not clickable

Tags: angular, protractor, wait, clickable

```
element.all(By.id(psearchResult.ptpID, psearchResult.mueResCardHeader))
  .filter((mueElementColClick, index) => {
    return mueElementColClick.getText().then((mueElementColClickText) => {
      mueElementColClickText = stestDataResultsets.expectedPTPHeader[index];
      console.log('mueElementColClickText '+mueElementColClickText);
      browser.waitForAngular();
      return mueElementColClickText;
    });
  }).click();
```

There are 3 lines of text on the page and each link can be clicked to expand the below text. The above code will click the first two lines of text and they expand - but when it comes to the third, when it tries to click it, it says it is not clickible.

Answer (score 0):

What should do this line:

`mueElementColClickText = stestDataResultsets.expectedPTPHeader[index];` ?

`mueElementColClickText` is a defined variable. You are trying to set new value to it, aren't you?

Maybe you'd rather like to compare `mueElementColClickText` with `stestDataResultsets.expectedPTPHeader[index];`?

Another thing: `filter` returns an `ElementArrayFinder` [see the doc: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter]

In last line you should change `.click();` to `.first().click();`

Answer (score 0):

mueElementColClickText is not defined - but used to get the value from the promise.

I don't see the value in doing compare as I assign it that value, so they should be equal.

.first().click(); - as I said there are 3 links on the page - if I do .first().click(); - the first link is always clicked.

Thanks for your reply - can I check that it is clickable before i click ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what might be happening:

I'm putting the 3 links to be clicked into the element.all array.

Then I'm doing one click to expend all 3 links.

So the first link is clicked and a 20 lines of a table opens under it. At this time the browser is trying to find the second link to click but cannot - Anybody else have this issue or how solve it ?? Thks